# react giving me weird error. dont seem to understand whats going on

Tags: reactjs, redux

i have a array of users with name and email.
in the parent components i am looping this array like this

```
return(<div>{       
                users.map((user)=>{
                    return <UserBox key={user.name} user={user}></UserBox>;   
                })
               }
               </div>
            );
```

**Userbox** is the child component with this

```
return (
            <p>
                {this.props.user.name} {this.props.user.rating}
            </p>
        );
```

But i am getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {s, e, c}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (at UserBox.js:15)
    in UserBox (at Users.js:30)
    in div (at Users.js:27)
    in Users (created by Connect(Users))
    in Connect(Users) (at Dashboard.js:18)
    in div (at Dashboard.js:15)
    in div (at Dashboard.js:14)
    in main (at Dashboard.js:13)
    in Dashboard (created by UserIsAuthenticated(Dashboard))
    in UserIsAuthenticated(Dashboard) (created by Connect(UserIsAuthenticated(Dashboard)))
    in Connect(UserIsAuthenticated(Dashboard)) (created by RouterContext)
    in div (at App.js:39)
    in App (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router (at index.js:33)
    in Provider (at index.js:32)
    at invariant (invariant.js:42)
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:6748)
    at createChild (react-dom.development.js:7012)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:7282)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:7651)
    at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:7756)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:7747)
    at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:7998)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:8229)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:10224)
```

Comment: `this.props.user.name` or `{this.props.user.rating}` is almost certainly an object. Check what those actually look like.

Comment: use component as a self closing <UserBox key={user.name} user={user} />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Userbox component:

```
return (
  <p>
    {this.props.user.name} {this.props.user.rating}
  </p>
);
```

Check that `this.props.user.name` or `this.props.user.rating` are **strings** and not **objects**.

Comment: This values are coming from redux and i am not sure how that works i added toString to the above like this and now it works <div>
                {this.props.team.name.toString()} {this.props.team.rating.toString()}
            </div>